# "new self()" equivalent in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a class like the following:

```
const Module = {
  Example: class {
    constructor(a) {
      this.a = a;
    }

    static fromString(s) {
      // parsing code
      return new Module.Example(a);
    }
  }
}
```

This works so far, but accessing the current class constructor via the global name `Module.Example` is kind of ugly and prone to breaking.

In PHP, I would use `new self()` or `new static()` here to reference the class that the static method is defined in. Is there something like this in Javascript that doesn't depend on the global scope?

Comment: I would learn how prototype work first, as the "class" you're creating is already an object.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can just use `this` inside the static method. It will refer to the class itself instead of an instance, so you can just instantiate it from there.

If you need to access the constructor from an instance function, you can use `this.constructor` to get the constructor without specifying its name.

Here's how:

```js
const Module = {
  Example: class Example {
    constructor(a) {
      this.a = a;
    }

    static fromString(s) {
      // parsing code
      return new this(s);
    }

    copy() {
      return new this.constructor(this.a);
    }
  }
}

const mod = Module.Example.fromString('my str');
console.log(mod) // => { "a": "my str" 
console.log(mod.copy()) // => { "a": "my str" }
console.log('eq 1', mod === mod) // => true
console.log('eq 2', mod === mod.copy()) // => false
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it from a non-static method?

Comment: @orrd you can use `this.constructor`, and pass the required arguments (e.g. `return new this.constructor('newStr');`. I've updated the answer to include an example

Comment: doesn't seem to work in all cases... `this` seems to be undefined if the static method is used inside a map?

Comment: @igorsantos07 try saving it first under a different name, e.g. `let thisBackup = this;` then inside your `map` (or similar) function, manipulate `thisBackup` instead.