# Reference same class

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
class MyClass{

  someMethod(): MyClass{
     return new MyClass();
  }

}
```

How to reference current class, without explicitly passing the name?

Something like this:

```
class MyClass{

  someMethod(): self{
     return new self();
  }

}
```

Obviously that doesn't work, but you get the idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return new self equivalent in TypeScript for class inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72726950/return-new-self-equivalent-in-typescript-for-class-inheritance)

Comment: Here's the JS Q that gets you to the TS problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44627709/3001761

Comment: Does it need to be typescript?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72726950/return-new-self-equivalent-in-typescript-for-class-inheritance

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript will not recognize `this.constructor` as callable. Use `Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor` to get a reference to it instead.

This is the most straightforward way of doing this with strict type safety:

```js
class SelfReference {
    /**
     * Assign some constructor arguments to the instance for testing.
     */
    constructor(private a: number, private b: number) {}

    /**
     * Create a new instance of `Object.prototypeOf(this).constructor`.
     */
    newInstance(...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof SelfReference>) {
        const { constructor } = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
        return new constructor(...args);
    }
}

const firstReference = new SelfReference(1, 2);
const newReference = firstReference.newInstance(3, 4);

console.log({ firstReference, newReference });
```

Logs:

```
[LOG]: {
  "firstReference": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  },
  "newReference": {
    "a": 3,
    "b": 4
  }
}
```

I would not recommend doing this though, it's a pretty ugly anti-pattern.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCmIBmAleT4Cd4Dtj2gG8AoaM6AegCorTzoroBBKASwHMdoIB7AWwLAeOCABdMAV2CiemaGEzsJAnKJgzoogBYFWI0WDwEkszfDF72AOjrkqFW9CH7J02QAoADplYA3MKIEYABc0DjKAEZYADTQ3n4BBBGh4XxRmACURAC+xI7UtPQM0ADC2InyYfAA7tB6Yob40DxI0AAGAPIRAFbw0lbePDKiAJ6e8B1I7tqsEBlWzmKuMphtNkX2jjg1AJL6jfDuVscK7BChJcJLUisACgpgAoGYEAA8o+MtcIio6Fi4+AAfFkSEVyItREQnFdxDdTNloABeaBdXr9djwUS3TBDIZjCZTGZzADcjno2FEEkwXG2tQhyw8xyspxJjlyuWIEOgSFYL1EaAw2CMSKqtQQyAF-yM7gAjLEAEwZUlc2mSoVNZE8vlqgHwKy0vYNaUAZliABYlXlFjwQHqQDx2O5CNzeWIdUZYqq-uqCNklUA)

Comment: Rather than [cross-posting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73328117/157247), I suggest just posting the answer to [the earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72726950/return-new-self-equivalent-in-typescript-for-class-inheritance) instead.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by using `getPrototypeOf`:

```
Class myclass {

  constructor() {}
  class(): this {
    const ctor = Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor;
    return new ctor();
  }
}
```

Using the `ctor()`, we are not calling `myclass` specifically!

[Mozilla - Globa_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass {

    returnClass(): MyClass {
        return new (this.constructor as typeof MyClass)();
    }
}

const x: MyClass = new MyClass();
const newClass: MyClass = x.returnClass();
```

Comment: This is not type-safe due to the `as typeof MyClass` assertion.

Answer (score -1):

`this` is what you want !

```
class Foo {
    foo(): this {
        return this;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo { }


const bar: Bar = new Bar().foo();
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=34&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQGaIBQEoAuaAFwAsBLGNTW6AJwFMSBXegO1MogG51MAvqiGpQkGACEw9aIwAeJRuwAmMBEmTQRo%20OwgloAI2nEpMgLzR2jAO7QzBAHQ54BHkA)

Comment: seems to work for return type, but in the body I want to return a new instance of this (class is supposed to be immutable)... and `new this()` does not work

Comment: actually it does not work for return type either. Because "MyClass is not assignable to this"

Comment: do you want an instance of the class to be returned or the class itself?

Comment: In this case, the `foo` method returns a reference to the same class. For example:
`const bar1 = new Bar(); const bar2 = bar1.foo(); console.assert(bar1 === bar2)`

Comment: This returns a reference to the same instance, not a new instance.

Answer (score -1):

Does this do what you want? You can explicitly grab the current constructor to make a "new this".

```js
class MyClass{

  someMethod(){
     return new this.constructor();
  }
}

let x = new MyClass();
let y = x.someMethod();
```

Comment: This is Javascript, not Typescript

Comment: just add trivial type annotations, javascript runs in the stack overflow widget, typescript does not.

Comment: What type annotations?

Comment: This actually will work in JS but TypeScript does not recognize `this.constructor` as callable, it knows it only as type `Function`.

Answer (score -1):

## Here is a TypeScript solution.

There doesn't seem to be a way to use the `this` keyword in the function signature of a static method or the `this.constructor` keyword in the function signature of an instance method, both which would be equivalent to the `Self` keyword in other languages. However, as the `this`/`this.constructor` keyword would represent an instance of the `Foo` class, and an instance of a class which extends from the `Foo` class can be returned from a function with return type `Foo`, the return type of the function doesn't have to be a special keyword, but can just be the class name.

```js
class Foo {
  static createNewClass(): Foo {
    return new this();
  }
  
  name = "Foo";
  
  createNewClass(): Foo {
    return new (this.constructor as typeof Foo)();
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  name = "Bar";
}

const foo = new Foo();
const fooFromStaticMethod = Foo.createNewClass();
const fooFromMethod = foo.createNewClass();

const bar = new Bar();
const barFromStaticMethod = Bar.createNewClass();
const barFromMethod = bar.createNewClass();

console.log(fooFromStaticMethod.name, fooFromMethod.name, barFromStaticMethod.name, barFromMethod.name);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oQC5iwS2GmACcBTXUgOVIHcBhcKACgEoAuORFdDaMrAK7EAdtGG1oWABZ4IrANw8Avjx7CwAW1LQAvNABECePsUYeJcliq0GkOe05I0vPqUEixEptNkA6YPDC2MQCwFjwxNCQkgCeAA6k8ABmjiwKyqgqqKB20ABCYJGkAB5WwgAmMEbcGOpaugYFxCaZqNmB2NBJXHriNI7pAUFYXYiwxPAaAMo4%20MAAsm5S8OUNRv5kFNT0jPaKQ53d8OOTi9IrDUcbltY7duntw9AARoUNffmFgx0jr8Qn01mBDOy1Weia1y2Nl23yefwBIIuej%20kKs21szBYikeEHgIFIvhA8AA5kwjgCZrhgUsVr46qQADSjY4TDSI8p0zSMl6FClAhY0jn0pnw1nszlaLFAA)

Comment: This isn't type-safe because of the `as typeof Foo` assertion.